# How to remove a component of an object in a script?

Tags: unity, javascript, 3d-meshes, gameobject

I want to remove a *Sphere Mesh Renderer* component from a certain gameobject. I want to do this in a script. How do I do it? **I do not want to destroy the sphere itself, just the component**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [`Destroy`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) the component.

Be careful about which object you destroy, though. If you pass a GameObject to `Destroy`, you will destroy the entire thing. To destroy the component, you must pass a reference to that component specifically.

```
//example: destroys the MeshRenderer attached to this GameObject
var sphereMesh = GetComponent(MeshRenderer);
Destroy(sphereMesh);
```